# Can't create a node.js webserver using Openshift. Object #<Object> has no method 'listen'

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a simple node.js app on Openshift but I simply can't get it to run. My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "songcatapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.6.0",
    "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "0.x.x",
    "optimist": "0.2.x",
    "pkginfo": "0.2.x",
    "http-proxy": "0.7.3",
    "htmlparser": "1.7.3",
    "mongodb": "0.9.7-0",
    "ent": "0.x.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "bundleDependencies": [],

  "private": true,

  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js"
}
```

My server.js is:

```
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

console.log("ServerPort: "+server_port+", ServerIP: "+server_ip_address);

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('Hello Http');
});
console.log("http: %j", http);
http.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
  console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port " + port )
});
```

On application startup, the error I get is:

```
http.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'listen'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/53520a0be0b8cd914a000187/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:578:6)
```

I have deployed the application both on DotCloud and Amazon without any problems. I have been stuck on Openshift for a couple of days now!

Can anyone please help?

Many Thanks

Comment: You may want to try this way :
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end('Hello Http');
    }).listen(server_port);

Comment: Thanks but thats no different and doesn't explain why the http object appears to be the wrong object type

Answer (score 2):

`http.createServer()` creates and returns a server instance object, that instance is what has the server methods such as `listen()`:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end('Hello Http');
});
server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
  console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port " + port )
});
```

Comment: Sure, but why does the http object have no 'listen' method?. I think this is more related to dependencies/packages but I can find no up to date info on this currently.

Comment: `http` is just a singleton object that exports different methods for things like creating servers, starting client requests, etc. So if `http.listen()` existed, there would be no server context. This is especially an issue for https servers since you have to pass in configuration of certificates and keys and such when you call `https.createServer()`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'd love to say it does but it doesn't - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've loaded the `http` module.

Also, I think you want to create a `server`, and then call `server.listen`, or maybe chain the two statements together, like this:

```
var http = require('http')
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080 
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end('Hello Http');
}).listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
  console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port " + server_port )
});
```

Does your code run locally with "npm install" followed by "npm start"?